# how to make a button to read the text of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, speech-synthesis

I'm trying to make a button "Speak" that should basically read the text content of the previous div.

So for instance I have:

```
<div id="text1">Lorem ipsum</div>
<button id="btn">Speak</button>
<div id="text2">This is the second block</div>
<button id="btn">Speak</button>
```

and use such javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
speechSynthesis.cancel()
var u = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
var text_to_read = document.getElementById('step1');
jQuery.browser.chrome = /chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()); 
if(!jQuery.browser.chrome){
 u.rate = .2;
}
u.text = text_to_read.textContent;

btn.onclick = function () {speechSynthesis.speak(u);};
</script>
```

Now, instead of use "step1" in this line: var text_to_read = document.getElementById('step1');  I need to retrieve the text on the div immediately before the button.

Hope it is clear enough.

Sorry I'm not a JS coder.

Comment: id should be unique **id="btn"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery it's very simple:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').click(function(){
        alert($(this).prev().text());
    });
});
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/u4wmt9Lf/

Note: I also change the repeated `ids` to `classes`.

**EDIT:**

Try this pure JavaScript version, it should work for you:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
for(var i = 0, len = buttons.length; i < len; i++) {
    buttons[i].onclick = function (e) {
        var prev = e.target.previousElementSibling;
        var text = prev.innerText || prev.textContent;
        alert(text);
    }
}
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/u4wmt9Lf/11/

Comment: Yes, it should work this way!!! But unfortunately I can't use this syntax since it is in a wordpress environment. I've tried to change $ with jQuery but it doesn't work.

Comment: @user3590313 I update my answer with a pure JavaScript method, try it and let me know how it work :)

Comment: no, it doesn't work, I get this error: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'prev.innerText'). I've noticed that when I publish the code in wordpress I get: <div>..</div><p><button>...</button></p>

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').click(function(){
            speechSynthesis.cancel()    ;
      var text_to_read = $(this).prev().text();
        var u = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(text_to_read);
   speechSynthesis.speak(u); if(!/chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())){
     u.rate = .2;
    }
    u.text = text_to_read.textContent;

    });

});


<div id="text1">Lorem ipsum</div>
<button class="btn">Speak</button>
<div id="text2">This is the second block</div>
<button class="btn">Speak</button>
```

try this

UPDATED

Comment: this way it will only speak the text1 div content. It should read the content of any previous div.

Comment: same problem: I can't use this syntax since is in a wordpress environment. I've tried to change $ with jQuery, as I usually do, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is the text and buttons creating dynamically?

Comment: No, they are not created dynamically